# Is it possible to install 2 python packages via pip, simultaneously, in different terminals?

Tags: package-management, pip, opencv

My question is not about installing several packages in one line (all the questions I researched previously to asking this, talk about oneliner, but it is still sequential). I am installing `opencv-python`, specific version for my system: 3.4.0.14.

System:

```
uname -a
Linux orangepi4 4.4.179-rk3399 #2 SMP Thu May 6 10:53:22 CST 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Although I updated pip, it is taking a long time `building wheel for opencv-python (setup.py)...` (no questions regarding this, I know it is an issue with pre-built and pip versions, I'll just have to wait). I need that version specifically, and it must be with `python 2.7`, not `python 3.X`.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/orangepi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.3.4)
```

Now, I have seen that there is also a headless option, which should be faster.
[`pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless==3.4.0.14`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python-headless/3.4.0.14/) (Although contrib should also take longer). But I don't want to stop the opencv building process as it has already been running for an hour. Can I run in another terminal another `pip install` command WHILE there is another `pip install` running already? I haven't tried it because I do not want to risk having broken dependencies or problems with packages.

As a final note: from the only 3 packages proposed by pip, this is the only one that seems to be building. The rest kept giving errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==3.4.3.18 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 4.3.0.38)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.4.3.37
```

Comment: Why not test it yourself? Create a new [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), activate it in two terminals and install `opencv-python` in one and   `opencv-contrib-python-headless` in the other.

Comment: In the specific system, venvs cannot be used (no py venvs nor conda or similars). Good suggestion though. I ended up trying anyways without envs but it is hard to know as both were building, never ended up getting installed. I asked in case there is a specific "LINUX WON'T ALLOW IT" kind of answer., as I have found it for apt, yum and so on, but nothing for pip @muru